# What happens if I don't fall off the Wharf District when it starts collapsing?

Tags: bastion

The end of Bastion's first level, the Wharf District, was quite intense, what with everything falling apart and the whole stage collapsing behind me. Unfortunately, while trying to run away, I got a bit too caught up in the action, and, uh, rolled off of the stage. This wound up sending me to the next level, so clearly I was supposed to fall eventually, and yet I can't help but wonder what I might have found at the end, if I had not fallen.

What rewards lie at the end of the Wharf District, if any at all?

Comment: Bah, it's a shame we can't revisit levels... I just got to the last level.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a warp at the end that takes you to the next level, but the reward for reaching it is an achievement called "Ride the Wind."

Now I'm wondering if its worth the trouble for me to go and try for it again.

Comment: Actually, I got the achievement in spite of my clumsy falling, so that's not it. Maybe some different narration or something? Hm. Guess I'll find out on my second playthrough.

Comment: I just played through to it and ignored all the monsters and can confirm; At the end is just a few fragments and the warp that leads straight to the bastion.

Comment: Note that a Steam Achievement has been added for making it to the end of the Wharf District, [Ride The Wind](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41351/how-do-i-get-the-ride-the-wind-achievement).