# How do I get the Ride the Wind achievement?

Tags: achievements, bastion

I distinctly remember Bastion having 20 Steam achievements, because it's a nice even number, and I had them all. Now, however, [there are some more](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/bastion/achievements/), a new one being **Ride the Wind**, with no explanation text whatsoever:

[image: Ride the Wind]

How do I unlock that? I want it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy to get it seems. Just go through the first few scenes and you should get it automatically. Just don't fall off the edge in the Wharf District, because then the game will continue without awarding the achievement and you'll have to start over.

Comment: Oh, *that* Wharf District. All right. "You should get it automatically" isn't true, though. If you fall off, the game just continues (and doesn't award the achievement).

Comment: True, I thought you'd just die when you fall down.

Comment: The "falling off and missing the achievement" only happens in the sequence following the moment when you grab the core (ie, it's only relevant to the end of the level). Prior to that point falling off has the same effect as usual.

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely related to either the DLC that's coming out on the 14th, or to the Steam Winter Sale. The major Steam sales usually have in-game achievements linked to entries in drawings.

Oh, and apparently at one point the description said "Ride the Skyway in The Wharf", so that may be how you get it once it's active.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to Bastion free DLC / Update 08 ([released on 14th December](http://store.steampowered.com/news/6993/) on Steam)

This patch introduced four new achievements and new modes. Regarding the specific achievement you are asking for, here it is the description.

**Ride the Wind**

> Use the Skyway in the Wharf District.

The other three achievements are:

**All in the Mind**

> Complete the Stranger's Dream with five or more Shrine Idols invoked.

**About the Author**

> Complete the Stranger's Dream with all ten Shrine Idols invoked.

**Hard Bargain**

> Earn a total of at least 1,000,000 points in Score Attack Mode.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the first core, don't fall.  Roll through walls and such, and hit the sky thing at the end to get to the bastion.  If you fall you'll still go to the bastion.