# Do I have to restart the game if I miss "Ride the Wind"?

Tags: bastion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the Ride the Wind achievement?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41351/how-do-i-get-the-ride-the-wind-achievement)

In Bastion, I have already completed the Wharf District and the game does not let me replay the level, but I don't have the Ride the Wind achievement. Do I have to restart the game to get this, or do I get another chance later in the game?

Comment: IIRC, you _did_ have to start all over.  Fortunately it's one of the first levels in the game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Help & Options menu, Profiles lets you choose a different profile and then start a new game without deleting any progress. Then you can get the achievement as described in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44042/1787).

Comment: Doh. +1, this is so much easier than [what I'd concocted.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44285/23)