# I've missed the use the wind achievement. How can I get it without losing my save file?

Tags: steam, achievements, bastion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use the Skyway in the Wharf District?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44219/how-do-i-use-the-skyway-in-the-wharf-district)

This achievement requires you to leave the first level properly, by making use of the skyway at the end, rather than just falling midway there. Unfortunately, that's precisely what I did. The game offers no way back except for deleting your save file and starting everything over. The game's Steam Cloud enabled too, so things are trickier than usual.

How can I get that achievement (properly) without cheating?

Comment: See this answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44250/30863

Answer (score 3):

1. **Disable Steam Cloud for Bastion.**

   1. Right click on Bastion on your library.
   2. Click Properties.
   3. In the update tab, disable Steam cloud.
   4. Confirm.
2. **Move your save files away.** Proper path is supposed to start at the beginning, ain't so simple with this one.

   1. Open your Steam folder (under Program Files or whatever the Mac equivalent of that would be).
   2. Open your userdata folder.
   3. Open the folder associated with you. If there's only one user who's ever logged in to your computer, that's probably just one folder, otherwise you'll have a choice between account numbers. There's no obvious way to tell which is which, to be honest, so some trial and error might be required.
   4. Rename the **107100** folder to **107100_old**
3. **Get the achievement.** Start a new game, play through the level in its entirety, make sure you don't get knocked off. Otherwise just start a new game again. (If you still get your own savefile, you've picked the wrong user at step 2.3 or screwed up otherwise.)
4. Close Bastion and **restore your save files**.

   1. From where you were at step 2.4, delete the new **107100** folder
   2. Rename **107100_old** to **107100**.
5. **Re-enable Steam Cloud for Bastion** (see step 1.)
6. Bask in the newfound glory of your shiny new piece of coal, or useless coupon. (Limited time offer :P)